# Dbgrid - automatic post to database

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have a form with a query, a dataset, an editable dbgrid and an updatesql component. When I need to save the changes made in the dbgrid, I call this procedure:

```
procedure TEditCardDetailForm.SaveChanges;
begin
  Database1.StartTransaction;
  try
    Query2.ApplyUpdates;
    Database1.Commit;
  except
    Database1.Rollback;
    raise;
  end;
  Query2.CommitUpdates;
end;
```

However I want the changes to be applied automatically to the database when I press Enter or go to another row after editing a cell in the dbgrid - the way it is done when I use a TTable component. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you please specify which Delphi version are you using? Also, I'd suggest to avoid the use of BDE components if possible, since they are long deprecated.

Comment: So what ? D5 is more or less capable of making EXEs compatible to recent Windows. Even XP Themes avail from SoftGems. But BDE has rather poor compatibility report with newer Windows and no more development or support. In my last D5 days i used Firebird database back-end with UIB component set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two scenarios to handle here:

1. save changes when changing the grid row
2. save changes when changing the grid column

The first one is easy to implement by calling your `SaveChanges` procedure in the `AfterPost` event of the underlying dataset (`query2`, a `TClientDataSet`?).

For the second one you only have to call `query2.Post` after the column has changed. This can be done in the `OnDataChange` event of the `datasource`. Make sure to check for `Field <> nil` and the `dataset` being in *insert* or *edit* mode before calling `post`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right (please correct me if not) you have a TQuery with CachedUpdates set to true, but want it to behave as if it would not be using cached but immediate updates. If that is the case the way you have set up your TQuery contradicts your desired behaviour. Cached updates are to be "held" on the client side until you decide to manually post them to the database by using ApplyUpdates.

In case you can set CachedUpdates to false, you only need to do following:

1. Link the TUpdateSQL to the TQuery via its UpdateObject property.
2. Write the insert, update and delete statements and assign them to the InsertSQL, ModifySQL and DeleteSQL properties of the TUpdateSQL.

I guess you already have done these two things, so putting CachedUpdates to false should do it.

You can find more information on Cached Updates for Delphi 5 [here](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/Delphi/D5/dg/11_cache.html).

HTH

Comment: I changed CachedUpdates from True to False as you told me. Then I ran the project and on opening the form I got the message: "... EDBEngineError with message 'Invalid use of keyword. Token: Date, LineNumber: 4'" The query works fine when CachedUpdates is set to True.

Comment: That error usually appears because there is something in the SQL that your database engine (or BDE?) does not like. Can you please show us your SQL? Also, have you LiveRequest set to true (should not be, just asking if)?

Comment: Here is the query: 
SELECT cd.N, cd.hourstart, cd.hourfinish, o.objname, cd."work",  cd.worktime
FROM Card c JOIN CardDetail cd ON c.N=cd.card
JOIN objects o ON cd.project=o.N
WHERE c.worker=:worker AND c.data=CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
ORDER BY cd.hourstart;
I have set the worker parameter.

Comment: Not quite sure since i do not know which database you are using, but the " in *cd."work"* would make it fail on Oracle (just tested). Can you try removing it?

Comment: I do not know that database engine but it seems the problema lies on the *convert(date(getdate())* part. I'd suggest to try changing it

Comment: But as I said there are no problems with the query when CachedUpdates=True. I have no explanation. Anyway, I did it the way Uwe Raabe proposed.